# Reactjs - Updation in Reactjs build dynamically. Client wants to update hostname and port in ReactJs build. How he can do it?

Tags: reactjs

Actually, i created react js build through npm run build in create-react-app and given to client. Now client wants to replace or update with his hostname and port in build through config file. How can we do it dynamically after creation of build?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change hostname or port, if you build your project you just need to upload it in your host (like www folder) because it's just HTML CSS, then it will show your project if you enter your domain.

But if you want to change the default port in your localhost you can follow [this instruction](https://tech.amikelive.com/node-830/reactjs-changing-default-port-3000-in-create-react-app/)
I hope you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a server.js file in your src folder and paste the following code:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const history = require("connect-history-api-fallback");
const ip = require('ip');

app = express();

const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/build/"));

app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
app.use(
  history({
    disableDotRule: true,
    verbose: true
  })
);
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const hostname = ip.address();
app.listen(port, hostname);

console.log("Server Started " + port + " and IP address is " + ip.address());
```

And add a script in your package.json file as:

```
"production": "node server.js"
```

Now, when you do `npm run production` your React App will get the ip address of your device and port. And when you give the production build to your client, he/she can simple change the port/hostname.
Note: `hostname` has be a string and you can specify it manually e.g

```
hostname = "192.168.8.1";
```

Checkout this [react-starter-project](https://github.com/mughalhere/react-starter-kit), I made to simplify such process